# FedEx error: Special service invalid 8200

Tags: fedex

I'm trying to connect to FedEx International WebServices API for Ship Service.

I'm using WSDL of v13.

Below is my SOAP Content:

```
<ns:ProcessShipmentRequest xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v13">
   <ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
      <ns:UserCredential>
         <ns:Key>GHmnVXAyWqWUemqD</ns:Key>
         <ns:Password>1VYHs6O1vhKA3xPVAExhx1vUB</ns:Password>
      </ns:UserCredential>
   </ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
   <ns:ClientDetail>
      <ns:AccountNumber>510087666</ns:AccountNumber>
      <ns:MeterNumber>100115929</ns:MeterNumber>
   </ns:ClientDetail>
   <ns:Version>
      <ns:ServiceId>ship</ns:ServiceId>
      <ns:Major>13</ns:Major>
      <ns:Intermediate>0</ns:Intermediate>
      <ns:Minor>0</ns:Minor>
   </ns:Version>
   <ns:RequestedShipment>
      <ns:ShipTimestamp>2015-04-17T12:51:03.404660Z</ns:ShipTimestamp>
      <ns:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns:DropoffType>
      <ns:ServiceType>INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY</ns:ServiceType>
      <ns:PackagingType>FEDEX_25KG_BOX</ns:PackagingType>
      <ns:TotalWeight>
         <ns:Units>LB</ns:Units>
         <ns:Value>40.0</ns:Value>
      </ns:TotalWeight>
      <ns:Shipper>
         <ns:Contact>
            <ns:CompanyName>Your Company</ns:CompanyName>
            <ns:PhoneNumber>4354454365746</ns:PhoneNumber>
         </ns:Contact>
         <ns:Address>
            <ns:StreetLines>3121 W Government Way</ns:StreetLines>
            <ns:StreetLines>Seattle</ns:StreetLines>
            <ns:City>Seattle</ns:City>
            <ns:StateOrProvinceCode>WA</ns:StateOrProvinceCode>
            <ns:PostalCode>98199</ns:PostalCode>
            <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
            <ns:CountryName>United States</ns:CountryName>
            <ns:Residential>false</ns:Residential>
         </ns:Address>
      </ns:Shipper>
      <ns:Recipient>
         <ns:Contact>
            <ns:PersonName>Agrolait</ns:PersonName>
            <ns:PhoneNumber>3210588558</ns:PhoneNumber>
         </ns:Contact>
         <ns:Address>
            <ns:StreetLines>1010 EASY ST</ns:StreetLines>
            <ns:StreetLines>Apt# 11</ns:StreetLines>
            <ns:City>OTTAWA</ns:City>
            <ns:StateOrProvinceCode>ON</ns:StateOrProvinceCode>
            <ns:PostalCode>K1A0B1</ns:PostalCode>
            <ns:CountryCode>CA</ns:CountryCode>
            <ns:Residential>false</ns:Residential>
         </ns:Address>
      </ns:Recipient>
      <ns:ShippingChargesPayment>
         <ns:PaymentType>SENDER</ns:PaymentType>
         <ns:Payor>
            <ns:ResponsibleParty>
               <ns:AccountNumber>510087666</ns:AccountNumber>
               <ns:Contact>
                  <ns:PersonName>Your Company</ns:PersonName>
                  <ns:CompanyName>Your Company</ns:CompanyName>
                  <ns:PhoneNumber>4354454365746</ns:PhoneNumber>
               </ns:Contact>
               <ns:Address>
                  <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
               </ns:Address>
            </ns:ResponsibleParty>
         </ns:Payor>
      </ns:ShippingChargesPayment>
      <ns:CustomsClearanceDetail>
         <ns:ClearanceBrokerage>BROKER_UNASSIGNED</ns:ClearanceBrokerage>
         <ns:DutiesPayment>
            <ns:PaymentType>SENDER</ns:PaymentType>
            <ns:Payor>
               <ns:ResponsibleParty>
                  <ns:AccountNumber>510087666</ns:AccountNumber>
                  <ns:Contact>
                     <ns:PersonName>Your Company</ns:PersonName>
                     <ns:CompanyName>Your Company</ns:CompanyName>
                     <ns:PhoneNumber>4354454365746</ns:PhoneNumber>
                  </ns:Contact>
               </ns:ResponsibleParty>
            </ns:Payor>
         </ns:DutiesPayment>
         <ns:DocumentContent>NON_DOCUMENTS</ns:DocumentContent>
         <ns:CustomsValue>
            <ns:Currency>USD</ns:Currency>
            <ns:Amount>100.0</ns:Amount>
         </ns:CustomsValue>
         <ns:FreightOnValue>OWN_RISK</ns:FreightOnValue>
         <ns:CommercialInvoice>
            <ns:TaxesOrMiscellaneousChargeType>TAXES</ns:TaxesOrMiscellaneousChargeType>
            <ns:Purpose>SOLD</ns:Purpose>
            <ns:TermsOfSale>FOB_OR_FCA</ns:TermsOfSale>
         </ns:CommercialInvoice>
         <ns:Commodities>
            <ns:NumberOfPieces>1</ns:NumberOfPieces>
            <ns:Description>[CARD] Graphics Card</ns:Description>
            <ns:CountryOfManufacture>US</ns:CountryOfManufacture>
            <ns:Weight>
               <ns:Units>LB</ns:Units>
               <ns:Value>10.0</ns:Value>
            </ns:Weight>
            <ns:Quantity>1</ns:Quantity>
            <ns:QuantityUnits>Unit(s)</ns:QuantityUnits>
            <ns:UnitPrice>
               <ns:Currency>USD</ns:Currency>
               <ns:Amount>100.0</ns:Amount>
            </ns:UnitPrice>
            <ns:CustomsValue>
               <ns:Currency>USD</ns:Currency>
               <ns:Amount>100.0</ns:Amount>
            </ns:CustomsValue>
         </ns:Commodities>
      </ns:CustomsClearanceDetail>
      <ns:LabelSpecification>
         <ns:LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</ns:LabelFormatType>
         <ns:ImageType>PNG</ns:ImageType>
         <ns:LabelStockType>PAPER_4X6</ns:LabelStockType>
         <ns:LabelPrintingOrientation>BOTTOM_EDGE_OF_TEXT_FIRST</ns:LabelPrintingOrientation>
      </ns:LabelSpecification>
      <ns:ShippingDocumentSpecification>
         <ns:ShippingDocumentTypes>CERTIFICATE_OF_ORIGIN</ns:ShippingDocumentTypes>
      </ns:ShippingDocumentSpecification>
      <ns:RateRequestTypes>ACCOUNT</ns:RateRequestTypes>
      <ns:EdtRequestType>ALL</ns:EdtRequestType>
      <ns:PackageCount>1</ns:PackageCount>
      <ns:RequestedPackageLineItems>
         <ns:SequenceNumber>1</ns:SequenceNumber>
         <ns:Weight>
            <ns:Units>LB</ns:Units>
            <ns:Value>40.0</ns:Value>
         </ns:Weight>
         <ns:Dimensions>
            <ns:Length>17</ns:Length>
            <ns:Width>12</ns:Width>
            <ns:Height>3</ns:Height>
            <ns:Units>IN</ns:Units>
         </ns:Dimensions>
         <ns:PhysicalPackaging>BOX</ns:PhysicalPackaging>
      </ns:RequestedPackageLineItems>
   </ns:RequestedShipment>
</ns:ProcessShipmentRequest>
```

When I send the request I get Below Response:

```
(reply){
   HighestSeverity = "ERROR"
   Notifications[] = 
      (Notification){
         Severity = "ERROR"
         Source = "ship"
         Code = "8200"
         Message = "Special service is invalid."
         LocalizedMessage = "Special service is invalid."
      },
      (Notification){
         Severity = "WARNING"
         Source = "ship"
         Code = "7037"
         Message = "Harmonized code is missing or invalid for commodity (COMMODITY_INDEX}; estimated duties and taxes were not returned."
         LocalizedMessage = "Harmonized code is missing or invalid for commodity (COMMODITY_INDEX}; estimated duties and taxes were not returned."
         MessageParameters[] = 
            (NotificationParameter){
               Id = "COMMODITY_INDEX"
               Value = "1"
            },
      },
   Version = 
      (VersionId){
         ServiceId = "ship"
         Major = 13
         Intermediate = 0
         Minor = 0
      }
 }
```

Warning I can have fixed but the Special Service Invalid Error Persists. Please let me know If I'm passing some wrong value or if I'm missing some Value.

Note: I tried adding the special services like COD, but the issue is same.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a special service defined, this error is really odd. You need to email websupport at fedex dot com for resolution. FedEx error responses are terrible.